# vue-custom directive calling methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a  possibility to call vue-custom directive calling methods.
Like `v-on:click` or `v-on:focus`

So i want to develop a custom directive that can be utilized like :

```
<div z-hello="now('abc')" > A </div>
```

Comment: yes look at the example here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: is there an example with method call and args